# nodejs shows one records instead of three records in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js

Nodejs shows one records instead of three.

I have three records in the database under posts table but the nodejs code below is showing just one record instead of the three records. I will appreciate any help. can someone help me fix that.

```
exports.display = function (req, res) {
    var userid = 5;

    db.query('SELECT * FROM posts', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            res.json({
                message: 'issue with query'
            })
        } else {
            results.forEach(function (row) {

                var postid = row.id;
                var title = row.title;
                var content = row.content;
                var type = -1;

                console.log(title);

                db.query('SELECT count(*) as cntStatus,type FROM like_unlike WHERE postid=?', [postid], function (error, results, fields) {
                    const total_count = results[0].cntStatus;

                    var objs = [];
                    objs.push({
                        id: postid,
                        title: title,
                        content: content,
                        like: total_count
                    });

                    res.end(JSON.stringify(objs));
                })
            });
            console.log('Finish');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The title is misleading. It's not the node that's causing the issue, it's most likely your DB client. What's under `db` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the objs inside the loop change the scope, try this

```
exports.display = function (req, res) {
    var userid = 5;

    db.query('SELECT * FROM posts', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            res.json({
                message: 'issue with query'
            })
        } else {
            var objs = []; // <= Declare objs here
            var resultCount = results.length; // <= Declare count of total queries here
            successfulQueries = 0; // <= Increase this when a callback is called

            results.forEach(function (row) {

                var postid = row.id;
                var title = row.title;
                var content = row.content;
                var type = -1;

                console.log(title);

                db.query('SELECT count(*) as cntStatus,type FROM like_unlike WHERE postid=?', [postid], function (error, results, fields) {
                    successfulQueries++;
                    const total_count = results[0].cntStatus;

                    objs.push({
                        id: postid,
                        title: title,
                        content: content,
                        like: total_count
                    });

                    if (resultCount === successfulQueries) {
                        res.end(JSON.stringify(objs));
                        console.log('Finish');
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    });
}
```